# NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `products' for Wheyscrapper:Class

Tags: ruby

I'm building a small web scraper using Ruby and now I'm trying to refactor my code. Unfortunately, I'm encountering some errors while I'm refactoring my code. This is one of the errors.

Basically, I'm calling two separate methods in the first method which is whey_scrapper. Each of these two methods are basically responsible of scraping a specific item on the webpage. When I run and debug this code with byebug, I basically try to display the products or prices I've scraped but I get an error message saying that 'products' or 'prices' is undefined. This is my current code:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'
require 'byebug'
require 'csv'

class Wheyscrapper
    def whey_scrapper
        company = 'Body+%26+fit'
        url = "https://www.bodyenfitshop.nl/afslanken/afslank-toppers/?manufacturer=#{company}"
        unparsed_page = open(url).read
        parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
        product_scrapper
        prices_scrapper
        # csv = CSV.open('wheyprotein.csv', 'wb')       
    end 


    def product_scrapper
        products = Array.new
        product_names = parsed_page.css('div.product-primary')
        product_names.each do |product_name| 
            product = {
                name: product_name.css('h2.product-name').text
            }
            products << product 
        end
    end

    def prices_scrapper
        prices = Array.new
        product_prices = parsed_page.css('div.price-box')
        product_prices.each do |product_price|
            price = {
                amount: product_price.css('span.price').text
            }
            prices << price
        end
    end
    byebug
    whey_scrapper
end
```

Comment: If you want to call a variable that's defined inside one method from inside another method, you need to define it as an instance variable so `@parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)` then you can call `@parsed_page` inside other methods.

Comment: Tip: Consider `[ ]` instead of `Array.new` unless you're adding arguments like `Array.new(size)` or `Array.new(size, default)`.

Comment: Remember that [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is the tool you want here. It can quickly convert one array to another of the same size, avoiding the array initialization, and manual appending.

Comment: It's also spelled "[scraper](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scraper)" not "[scrapper](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scrapper)".

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here, but to make it more Ruby you'd consider making those *lazy-initialized* and giving them names that reflect that:

```
class Wheyscrapper
  URL = "https://www.bodyenfitshop.nl/afslanken/afslank-toppers/?%s"

  def initialize(company:)
    @company = company
    # Use encode_www_form to encode query-string parameters
    @url = URL % URI.encode_www_form(manufacturer: company)
  end

  def document
    # Lazy-initialize a parsd version of the page
    @document ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
  end

  def products
    document.css('div.product-primary').map do |product_name| 
      {
        name: product_name.css('h2.product-name').text
      }
    end
  end

  def prices
    document.css('div.price-box').map do |product_price|
      {
        amount: product_price.css('span.price').text
      }
    end
  end
end
```

This fixes a lot of the data propagation problems you had in your original. When you declare a variable it's a *local* variable, meaning it doesn't exist outside of that particular call of that particular method. If you want to persist it for longer you need to use *instance variables*, as in `@products`, or you need to define methods that return the data you need.

The above approach combines that, using a lazy-initialized instance variable to persist the parsed document, and exposes that as a method the other methods can use.

Now you can spin this up:

```
scraper = WheyScraper.new(company: "Body & Fit")
```

Where that should enable everything to be available directly:

```
scraper.prices
scraper.products
```

When you learn how to use Ruby effectively you'll often find solutions to your problems that are really minimal. Usually a lot of Ruby code is a sign that it's not being used properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should be refactored in a better way but this should at least work without refactor, based on my comments above

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'
require 'csv'

class Wheyscrapper
  def whey_scrapper
    company = 'Body+%26+fit'
    url = "https://www.bodyenfitshop.nl/afslanken/afslank-toppers/?manufacturer=#{company}"
    unparsed_page = open(url).read
    @parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
    product_scrapper
    prices_scrapper
    # csv = CSV.open('wheyprotein.csv', 'wb')
  end


  def product_scrapper
    @products = Array.new
    product_names = @parsed_page.css('div.product-primary')
    product_names.each do |product_name|
      product = {
        name: product_name.css('h2.product-name').text
      }
      @products << product
    end
  end

  def prices_scrapper
    @prices = Array.new
    @product_prices = @parsed_page.css('div.price-box')
    @product_prices.each do |product_price|
      price = {
        amount: product_price.css('span.price').text
      }
      @prices << price
    end
  end
end

w = Wheyscrapper.new.whey_scrapper
```

Comment: hey @lacostenycoder I did as you told me. But unfortunately the methods are not working as they should. It's simply not storing the data correctly in the csv. This is my code: https://codeshare.io/anMOv3